# Scrolling through div without scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to get this sidebar to be scrollable. Right now you can navigate through it by clicking items within in (using jQuery to animate the margin upon clicking an item), but I'd like to add scrolling functionality as well.

I tried overflow: scroll without success. Any help?

https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/xpXZVW

```
$('.track-name').click(function() {

  //Remove active class from all other track names
  $('.track-name').not(this).removeClass('active');

  //Add active class on clicked track name
  $(this).addClass('active');

  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

  var scrollAmount = id * -50;
  console.log(scrollAmount);

  $('.track-name-inner').animate({ marginTop: scrollAmount }, 300);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why they disappear when I click them but that's OK.

You needed to set an explicit height on the container in order for overflow:scroll to work.

Working codepen: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvXpva

```
.track-name-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 150px; 
}
```

Comment: Use `.track-name-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}` to hide the scrollbars after using his solution.

Comment: He will have to rework his `.track-name` click event also, because scrolling totally messes it up